# Unable to detect usb camera

Tags: linux, computer-vision, webcam, usb-camera

I am trying to use 5 usb cameras on `ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS` in `python` using `opencv`.

Individually they all work fine, but as I connect them all together the following happens:

- Mostly all cameras are successfully detected in start and are listed in `lsusb` as well as `ls /dev/video*`, but as I try to use them through my code in python one of these 5 cameras disappear and error like `VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: index 0 is not correct!` is printed.A nd after that either `ls /dev/video*` does not show that camera or the camera name e.g. `video0` is automatically changed to e.g. `video6`. i know if we restart PC the device names are changed but in this case I am not rebooting.
- Sometimes the cameras are enlisted in both `lsusb` as well as in `ls /dev/video*` but while using `select timeout` appears.

Let me know if you need further information.

Answer (score 0):

1.Try first to show video streams from all cameras with ffmpeg (or ffplay): https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Webcam#Linux
Or with gstreamer.
2. OpenCV can capture video from webcam with any backend (ifit was comliled with it): https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ga023786be1ee68a9105bf2e48c700294d

For example: cv.CAP_V4L2, cv.CAP_GSTREAMER, cv.CAP_FFMPEG etc